# The type org.pentaho.metastore.api.IMetaStore cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, pentaho, kettle

i am trying to build a pentaho DI plugin in Eclipse. I have imported all the necessary jar files into the library.

[image]

But while coding it, i was facing this error:

```
The type org.pentaho.metastore.api.IMetaStore cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I got some reference stuff like :

1. http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?142513-What-s-best-way-to-get-nightly-containing-http-jira-pentaho-com-browse-PDI-6169
2. http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/The+Pentaho+Metastore

But i am not able to clearly understand this issue. Do i need to import some different jar ??
Please kindly help me in this !!!

**Pentaho DI Version :** 5.0.0 - GA
**OS :** 64 Bit Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are missing (at the very least) pentaho-metastore-5.0.0.1.jar. Also you won't need kettle-jdbc-5.0.0.1, it's not actually a core Kettle module.

Comment: Thanks @mattb_pdi... it worked.. added metastore-5.0.0.1.jar and now am not getting the error. :)